# Can't Align Left

Tags: vertical-alignment

[image]

How can i align these examples in the middle or left?
Here is the code I used:

```
\begin{align} 
\int3x^2dx\\
\int \frac{dx}{x^4}\\
\int x^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
\int \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{5}{2}}}\\
\int5a^3 da\\
\int \frac{dt}{t^3}\\
\int x^2t^3dx\\
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible to use also `flalign` or `alignat` enviroments:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}
\begin{flalign}
&\int3x^2dx\\
&\int \frac{dx}{x^4}\\
&\int x^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
&\int \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{5}{2}}}\\
&\int5a^3 da\\
&\int \frac{dt}{t^3}\\
&\int x^2t^3dx
\end{flalign}

\begin{alignat}{1}
&\int3x^2dx\\
&\int \frac{dx}{x^4}\\
&\int x^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
&\int \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{5}{2}}}\\
&\int5a^3 da\\
&\int \frac{dt}{t^3}\\
&\int x^2t^3dx
\end{alignat}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Add the alignment symbol `&` where you want to align in each line.

```
\begin{align}
     & \int3x^2dx                      \\
     & \int \frac{dx}{x^4}             \\
     & \int x^{\frac{3}{2}}            \\
     & \int \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{5}{2}}} \\
     & \int5a^3 da                     \\
     & \int \frac{dt}{t^3}             \\
     & \int x^2t^3dx
\end{align}
```

Answer (score 2):

As explained is @Amita's answer, you can put a `&` wherever you want to place the alignment point in the align environment. Hence, to align your equations on the left, you can simply begin each line with `&`.

If you want to align your equations on the middle, that is, if you want to center them, you could use the `gather` environment instead of `align`, as in the following example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{gather} 
\int3x^2dx\\
\int \frac{dx}{x^4}\\
\int x^{\frac{3}{2}}\\
\int \frac{dx}{x^{\frac{5}{2}}}\\
\int5a^3 da\\
\int \frac{dt}{t^3}\\
\int x^2t^3dx
\end{gather}
\end{document}
```

[image]